# How to extend a program that works for one file to act on every file in a directory

Tags: perl

I wrote a program to check for misspellings or unused data in a text file. Now, I want to check all files in a directory using the same process.

Here are a few lines of the script that I run for the first file:

```
open MYFILE, 'checking1.txt' or die $!;
@arr_file = <MYFILE>;
close (MYFILE);

open FILE_1, '>text1' or die $!;
open FILE_2, '>Output' or die $!;
open FILE_3, '>Output2' or die $!;
open FILE_4, '>text2' or die $!;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $#arr_file; $i++) {

    if ( $arr_file[$i-1] =~  /\s+\S+\_name\s+ (\S+)\;/ ) {
           print FILE_1 "name : $i  $1\n";
    }

...
```

I used only one file, `checking1.txt`, to execute the script, but now I want to do the same process for all files in the `all_file_directory`

Comment: This isn't hard. What have you tried and what went wrong? Is this homework?

Comment: File::Find - http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.24.0/ext/File-Find/lib/File/Find.pm

Comment: @yonyon100: Probably [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) since no recursion is required.

Comment: @Borodin was in the middle of editing my answer to include that as well

Answer (score 2):

Use an array to store file names and then loop over them. At the end of loop rename output files or copy them somewhere so that they do not get overwritten in next iteration.

```
my @files = qw(checking1.txt checking2.txt checking3.txt checking4.txt checking5.txt);
foreach my $filename (@files){
    open (my $fh, "<", $filename) or die $!;
    #perform operations on $filename using filehandle $fh
    #rename output files    
}
```

Now for the above to work you need to make sure the files are in the same directory. If not then:

- Provide absolute path to each file in `@files` array
- Traverse directory to find desired files

If you want to traverse the directory then see:

- [How do I read in the contents of a directory in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566/how-do-i-read-in-the-contents-of-a-directory-in-perl)
- [How can I recursively read out directories in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476019/how-can-i-recursively-read-out-directories-in-perl)

Also:

- [Use 3 args open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-autovivified-filehandles-a-perl-best-pract)
- [Always use strict; use warnings; in your Perl program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)

and give proper names to the variables. For eg:

```
@arr_file = <MYFILE>;
```

should be written as

```
@lines = <MYFILE>;
```

Comment: all my file are in the same directory, I got a lot of file actually more than 5 file,so I still can use as above?

Answer (score 2):

Your all files in same directory means put the program inside the directory then run it.

For read the file from a directory use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

```
while (my $filename =<*.txt>) # change the file extension whatever you want
{

    open my $fh, "<" , $filename or die "Error opening $!\n";

    #do your stuff here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Why not `use`[`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.24.0/ext/File-Find/lib/File/Find.pm)? Makes changing files in directories very easy. Just supply the start directory.
   It's not always the best choice, depends on your needs, but it's useful and easy almost every time I need to modify a lot of files all at once.
2. Another option is to just loop through the files, but in this case you'll have to supply the file names.
3. As [mkHun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3961170/mkhun) pointed out a `glob` can be helpful.